# How would I make this for loop into a flowchart?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, flowchart

```
 def buttons(self):
        labels = [
    '7','8','9','C',
    '4','5','6',' ',
    '1','2','3','-',  
    'esc','0','=','+', ]

    x = 1
    y = 0
    for label in labels:
        labelling = partial(self.calculate, label)
        tk.Button(self, text=label, width=3, relief='raised', bg="#87ceeb",
            command=labelling).grid(column=y, row=x)
        y += 1
        if y > 3:
            y = 0
            x += 1
    self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=19, bg="#afeeee")
    self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
```

Hi, how would I make this function into a flowchart, including the for loop and if loop? (The whole function) Thanks for reading

Comment: what do you mean "flowchart"? You want to diagram out the function's order-of-operations? Or the function should GENERATE a flowchart?

Comment: I want to diagram out the function's order-of-operations

Comment: I'd say you grab a piece of paper, a pen/pencil, and start drawing...

Comment: I don't think there's a single "official" way to represent code in chart form. Is this a homework assignment? Your teacher should have given you additional guidance regarding what to do.

Comment: No it's not, I have attempted it so much but I can't seem to fit the for loop and if loop together

Answer (score 0):

```
Set x=1, y=0
  |
 \|/
Create button at x,y
 /|\      |
  |      \|/
  |      increment y
  |         |
  |        \|/
  |       is y>3  ---yes ---> set y=0, increment x
  |          |                   |
  |          no                  |
  |         \|/                 \|/
  \---yes---are there more labels to make?
                 |
                 no
                 |
                \|/
               done
```

Pardon the bad ASCII art